# Any idea why one assign statement works and the other does not?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, firebird2.1

Here's my code:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * from tMedia where SKU = '" + SKU + "'";
FbCommand command = new FbCommand(strSQL, databaseConn);

if (databaseConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    databaseConn.Open();

FbDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();
data.Read();  //  only one row is returned

//  assignment to "x" is empty (277?)
string x = (string)data["ProductType"].ToString();

//  find product type and set flag for later testing
//  obviously, these don't work either!
if (data["ProductType"].ToString().Contains("Video "))
    videoFormat = true;
else if (data["ProductType"].ToString().Contains("Music: "))
    audioFormat = true;

//  coProductType.Text assignment is correct
coProductType.Text = data["ProductType"].ToString();
```

Comment: Comment about SQL injection and not using parameterized queries being bad.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Where does 277 come in? Why are you calling ToString *and* casting?

Comment: Comment about not using `using` blocks (and the Firebird documentation does use them).

Comment: Yuck: I didn't ask for a critique of the code, just help in getting it to work
Jon Skeet:  that's what's in the variable 'x' after the code executes... I haven't a clue what it is either.

Comment: Austin Salonen:  a using block is not going to solve the  questiion... it works on the second assignment, but not the first one.

Comment: Did you mean to have those spaces in "Video " and "Music: ", and if yes, are you sure those are returned by the query?

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?  Are you getting an error message, is it not retuning the value you expect, or something else?

Comment: @Dude, if you're sure about what is going to solve the problem and what is not going to solve the problem, but you still get the problem, then you're sure about something that is wrong. You are not providing enough information to tell what the problem is or how to solve it. The advice given will reduce uncertainties in your code; follow the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now... here's the code if anyone is interested...  I don't understand why moving the objects to outside of the method made it work.  If anyone can enlighten me, I would really appreciate it.

```
    string mediaFormat = "";
    bool video;
    bool audio;
    //---------------------------    populate the detail panel    ---------------------|
    private int PopulateDetailPanel(string SKU) {
        decimal convertedMoney;

        clearDetailPanel();  //  clear out old stuff

        //  now, find all data for this SKU
        if (databaseConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            databaseConn.Open();

        string strSQL = "SELECT * from tMedia where SKU = '" + SKU + "'";
        FbCommand command = new FbCommand(strSQL, databaseConn);

        //  find product type and set flag for later testing
        FbDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();
        data.Read();  //  only one row is returned

        coProductType.Text = data["ProductType"].ToString();  //  while we're here, might as well set it now
        mediaFormat = data["ProductType"].ToString();

        if (mediaFormat.Substring(0, 6) == "Video ")
            video = true;
        else if (mediaFormat.Substring(0, 7) == "Music: ")
            audio = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to deal with the problem that will occur when someone enters an invalid SKU and NO data rows are returned.

Comment: Can't happen... they have to select the record from a datagridview to populatae the detail... thanks anyway

Comment: Like you, I don't understand your solution.  One other remote possibility, if you are grabbing the SKU from the gridview, it might have trailing spaces that would cause the select to fail.

Comment: The select isn't failing... the assignment is, but it's now fixed... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only difference is the cast to string, it seems like a reasonable first step would be to remove that.  It shouldn't be necessary anyway.

Comment: I tried that... I also tried this, but to no avail...

                coProductType.Text = data["ProductType"].ToString();  //  while we're here, might as well set it now/n
                string xzzzz = data[40].ToString();
                string yzzzz = data.GetString(40);
                string zzzzz = coProductType.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: At what point were you examining the variable values?  If you waited until after the function, then coProductType.Text could be correct, but x would be out of scope and there could be another x in a broader scope that has value 277.

Comment: djs:  that might account for it... by moving the variables outside of the method/function, the scope changes... maybe that's what it needed... thanks for the suggestion...